# how to create top left and bottom right border with different color?

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to create a border on a div with two different color on the top left and the bottom right.
Can't find solution, with images or directly on css.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the below example.

You can use position set to`absolute` for the two red sections and they can be positioned with respect to the div with class `box`, which has its position set to `relative`.

```css
.box {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border-left: 10px solid darkblue;
  border-top: 10px solid darkblue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  border-right: 10px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="top-left"></div>
  <div class="bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the example of Naren Murali or you can create [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), so you do not need as much HTML.

I created two pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`

[:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. It is inline by default.

[:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

In CSS, ::after creates a pseudo-element that is the last child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. It is inline by default.

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    background: grey;
}
div:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
    border-left: 5px solid blue;
}
div:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    border-right: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need extra elements or pseudo elements, you can do easily with multiple background:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(red,red)   0 0,
   linear-gradient(red,red)   0 0,
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) 100% 100%,
   linear-gradient(blue,blue) 100% 100%,
  #ccc;
 padding:5px;
 background-size:80px 20px,20px 80px;
 background-origin:content-box;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```